# How to add a new board to uboot under board/ti

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, bsp

I am looking at u-boot after 5 years. It seems that adding a custom board under boards/ti is not trivial anymore.
I copied board/ti/am335x to board/ti/pm335x
Then copied include/configs/am335x_evm.h to include/configs/pm335x_evm.h
Added the board entry to 
arch/arm/mach-omap2/am33xx/Kconfig
by copying:
config TARGET_AM335X_EVM to config TARGET_PM335X_EVM.

In am335x_evm_defconfig:

How does CONFIG_AM33XX directly select board/ti/am335x ?
I replaced CONFIG_AM33XX to CONFIG_TARGET_PM335X_EVM=y

Why does my board never get selected even after specifying TARGET_PM335X_EVM=y

Why does config and compilation fail?

How do you add a new board ?

Comment: Perhaps you need some studying steps? Reading documentation, for a starter?